# Div is overlapped when add class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three div

- Navbar
- Banner
- Content

What I want to do is make background of navbar full width, but all elements inside navbar have margin and center, also banner and content. So I add nav-topmost class to the div that contains navbar. But when I add this class. Three div is overlapped. Without this class, everything work fine but my navbar not full width.

Can anyone help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance !

Here is my code :

```css
.nav-topmost
{
  margin-bottom:20px;
  padding:0;
  height:50px;
  background:#000;
}
.banner
{
  height:100px;
  background:#eee;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
.content
{
  background:#bbb;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.0.0/united/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid nav-topmost">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="pull-right">
     <a href="#">SET HOME</a>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
     <input type="submit" value="Search" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
   </div>
            <div class="banner">
              BANNER
            </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  Some contents
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some correction here and hope this is what you want.
I changed the structure and put .nav-topmost's div out of .container's div.
http://jsfiddle.net/amitv1093/z2eoxm4v/

---html---

```
     <nav class="nav-topmost">
<div class="container">
        <div class="pull-right">
                    <a href="#">SET HOME</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
          </div>
  </nav>


        <div class="container">

            <div class="banner">
              BANNER
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  Some contents
  </div>

</div>
```

---css---

```
.nav-topmost
    {
      margin-bottom:20px;
      padding:10px 0px;

      background:#000;
    }
```

Comment: @Quang Vinh, Dont  modify the properties of bootstrap classes.It is the matter of div positioning only.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
.nav-topmost
{
    position:relative;
    top:0;
}

.container, .clearfix, .banner{
    width:100%;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/waqj5tL1/)

Answer (score 0):

remove `nav-topmost` class from container-fluid element and add it to the main navigation bar like this

```
<div class="container-fluid"> /* Remove nav-topmost */
        <div class="container">
            <div class="clearfix nav-topmost"> /* Add Here */
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a href="#">SET HOME</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="banner">
              BANNER
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```